# What is the form of partial fraction decomposition when the exponent is inside the factor?

Tags: partial-fractions

I have a partial fraction problem where I need to decompose
$$\frac{1}{(-2x-x^4)}$$
which becomes
$$\frac{1}{(x)(-x^3-2)}.$$

I'm used to dealing with partial fractions where the factor $(x-2)$ is raised to the third power, like $(x-2)^3$, but what do I do when the third power is inside the factor, like $(x^3-2)$?

It no longer seems to fit any of the [forms for partial fraction decomposition](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/PartialFractions.aspx), and yet, apparently [it can still be done](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=1%2F%28-2x-x%5E4%29). How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a numerator with one less power of $x$ than the term in the denominator, so you would write $\frac {-1}{x^4+2x}=\frac ax + \frac {bx^2+cx+d}{x^3+2}$ and find $a,b,c,d$  If we multiply by $x$ and take the limit as $x \to 0$ we find $a=-\frac 12$.  If we clear the fractions we find $-1=-\frac 12(x^3+2)+bx^3+cx^2+dx$ which gives $b=\frac 12,c=0,d=0$ and $$\frac {-1}{x^4+2x}=-\frac 1{2x} + \frac {x^2}{2(x^3+2)}$$
[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1%2F(2x)%2Bx%5E2%2F(2(x%5E3%2B2))) confirms this.

Answer (score 0):

If so you need to write before 
$$x^3+2=(x+\sqrt[3]2)(x^2-\sqrt[3]2x+\sqrt[3]4).$$

The answer would be 
$$\frac{1}{-x^4-2x}=-\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{2x-\sqrt[3]2}{6((x^2-\sqrt[3]2x+\sqrt[3]4)}+\frac{1}{6(x+\sqrt[3]2)}.$$